# Ubuntu compatible laptops

Tags: hp

I am looking to buy either of the following two laptops but wanted to ensure they were compatible with Ubuntu. Both seem to match laptop names as 'okay' but the details of the specs seem to be slightly different, which leaves me confused!

- HPM6-1205SO/i5/8GB (HP Envy M6 ??)
- HP15-J028EO/i5/12G (HP Envy 15 ??)

Your help much appreciated.

Many thanks, Melanie

Comment: Purchase a system with Ubuntu pre-installed, you have a choice of several vendors.

Comment: Both are Linux-compatible: Envy M6: https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?view=search_computer&computer_model=Envy+M6
Envy 15: https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?view=search_computer&computer_model=Envy+15

Answer (score 0):

I use linlap.com to check out potential laptops.  The m6 has one user who thinks "good" describes his linux experience, but admits can't get the wireless working.  The 15 has more users, but many more bad votes.  For Ubuntu, I'd keep looking.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of useful links:

- [linlap.com](http://www.linlap.com/laptops) is a handy wiki page
- Ubuntu Forums: [Laptop COMPATIBILITY List](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1543006) thread: use the in-thread search
- [Ubuntu Desktop certified hardware](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/desktop/) page

Generally the model name is not so important: the internals are. Find out what they are for those models and try to Google to see if e.g. the wireless card has issues with Ubuntu.